# RDF Interlinking with other dataset

Tags: java, dataset, rdf, dbpedia, linkage

I have this RDF file:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://relation/" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://Group/row100">
    <j.0:Codice>VC</j.0:Codice>
    <j.0:Nome>Vercelli</j.0:Nome>
    <j.0:Regione>Piemonte</j.0:Regione>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://Group/row63">
    <j.0:Codice>MT</j.0:Codice>
    <j.0:Nome>Matera</j.0:Nome>
    <j.0:Regione>Basilicata</j.0:Regione>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://Group/row30">
    <j.0:Codice>CA</j.0:Codice>
    <j.0:Nome>Cagliari</j.0:Nome>
    <j.0:Regione>Sardegna</j.0:Regione>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://Group/row57">
    <j.0:Codice>LU</j.0:Codice>
    <j.0:Nome>Lucca</j.0:Nome>
    <j.0:Regione>Toscana</j.0:Regione>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://Group/row71">
    <j.0:Codice>PD</j.0:Codice>
    <j.0:Nome>Padova</j.0:Nome>
    <j.0:Regione>Veneto</j.0:Regione>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://Group/row14">
    <j.0:Codice>TN</j.0:Codice>
    <j.0:Nome>Trento</j.0:Nome>
    <j.0:Regione>TrentinoAltoAdige</j.0:Regione>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

How I can do interlinking my file with other external Dataset as DBPEDIA?

I would like to use automated tools in Java code. I studied "Silk" but, it wants an ontology in input, while I don't want to provide an ontology in input.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by appending the literal, e.g. "Trentino", to the dbpedia URL "http://dbpedia.org/resource/" =>  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Trentino .

As some literals won't yield any result, e.g. "http://dbpedia.org/resource/TrentinoAltoAdige", you want to pre-process your data. In your case, alter the literal to "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Trentino_Alto_Adige" (see the pattern: insert a '_' before uppercase characters besides it's the first character).

Interlink your data with property e.g. `rdf:seeAlso` or, if you want link to wikipedia, e.g. `<http://purl.org/ontology/mo/wikipedia>`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way in Java to automatically create a link between the literal "Trentino" and the "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Trentino" page?

Comment: You don't want to create a link between a literal and a dbpedia URI. You want the triple : `<http://Group/row14> rdf:seeAlso <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Trento> .`

Comment: Ok, I understand. One question for you: The triple "<http://Group/row14> rdf:seeAlso <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Trentino>" should be added to my RDF file, or replace the existing one with the "http://relation/Regione" property?

Comment: Depends on your use case I would say. E.g. if you want to search your data you need the literal.

Comment: Ok, In my case, then I should write:
<http://Group/row14> rdf:seeAlso <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Trento> .
<http://Group/row14> rdf:seeAlso <http://dbpedia.org/resource/TN> .
<http://Group/row14> rdf:seeAlso <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Trentino_Alto_Adige> .

right? Can I write this?

Comment: You can write anything you want - the question is if you *want* it ;) . In your case, I would not link to the "Codice" literals as they seem to have a special meaning and `<dbpedia.org/resource/TN>` would be semantically to broad to make much sense. But as I said - you can do this of course - the property `rdf:seeAlso` is semantically broad in it's own case (but I would advise against linking use "Codice". You first should make clear for yourself what the "Codice" stands for and then find a way to link to a proper database or derive dbpedia URIs which make sense if this is possible.)